# Font awesome icons not displaying when i visit certain urls

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using the offline version of font awesome in a react project. I followed this [manual](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) to set it up. The problem i have is that the icons work on some pages but don't work on others. For example. They work on `localhost/courses` but don't work on `localhost/courses/1`. Or they work on `localhost/authors` but don't work on `localhost/authors/1`. I hope you see the pattern. How do i go about resolving this problem? Here is how i implemented my current solution.
I downloaded the offline bundle which contains several folders. Then i referenced `/css/all.css` and `/js/all.jsinside` inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<head>
  <link href="/folder/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="/folder/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="far fa-user"></i> <!-- uses regular style -->
  <i class="fal fa-user"></i> <!-- uses light style -->
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i> <!-- uses brands style -->
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your developer's console?

Comment: There is nothing in the console. However i checked the network tab and found out i can preview the all.css and all.js files on pages where the icons work. On the other hand, i can't preview the files on pages on which the icons don't work. When i click on them, i get the message ' You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.'

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your question

The safest way to do is by using full URL to your Font Awesome resources as follow (or other full URL if your URL is different then i provide):

```
<head>
  <link href="//localhost/courses/folder/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="//localhost/courses/folder/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="far fa-user"></i> <!-- uses regular style -->
  <i class="fal fa-user"></i> <!-- uses light style -->
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i> <!-- uses brands style -->
</body>
```

Other solution is using code as follow (by adding ../), but you must count how long your URL structur to make it work on particular page:

```
<head>
  <link href="../folder/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="../courses/folder/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

I hope this solution is work for you.

Comment: Thanks @kokom, unfortunately these solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using React's `%PUBLIC_URL%` which is available with react-scripts@0.5.0 and higher. You can read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder).  Here is how I am referencing the font-awesome files now, given they are inside a folder called `font-awesome` inside the `public` folder of a React project.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/font-awesome/css/all.css">
<script defer src="%PUBLIC_URL%/font-awesome/js/all.js"></script>
```